# WordPress footer styles loading to middle of page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

On the front page of my site, the footer content is loading to the bottom of the page, where it should. But the styles are loading to the middle of the page. As you'll see, I called a red background on the footer, but it's appearing behind a widget well above the footer html. It's a WordPress site, and I'm pretty certain the calls to the footer (WP_footer and get_footer) are being executed correctly.  I have a feeling that something else is disrupting the flow of the page, but I can't find it. The site is very early in development, and it's being done mobile-first, so it might look like a jumbled mess at views larger than phone. Here's the link:

-- link removed --

Thanks for taking a look!

PS. Working on a Mac mostly in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great answers.  And for teaching me a little more about DOM structure.  Lol.  I'm using a custom grid this time.  Apparently, I've gotten so used to using pre-made grid frameworks that clearing the floats didn't occur to me.  Since you were all right, I'm just giving the best answer to the first person who contributed.  But thank you all for, no pun intended, clearing this up for me.  It was driving me nuts.  Peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give style

```
float:left
```

to your footer and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a clearfix class to the footer, the floats are messing with it wrapping the content.

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
   <div id="footer" class="grid clearfix">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your widgets are floated left, the parent container  doesn't expand to the content height. You can add the following class in your css: `.grid {display:table; width:100%;}`